# compare String with general form java

Tags: java, arrays

i want to write java code that tells me whether or not the function that i have entered is in some predefined form. the predefined forms that I have are bcos(fx), bsin(fx) and btan(fx) where b and f are integer constants.

if the user randomly gives input like 3cos(2x) and 700sin(45x) respectively, the code should detect that the input is of the forms bcos(fx) and bsin(fx) respectively.

the code should be as efficient as possible for efficiency because my program has 50 predefined forms.

Comment: Regex. Regex. Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Look for regexes.

A simple one would look like this:

```
\d+(sin|cos|tan)\(\d+x\)
```